# How to retrieve Stripe card element object by DOM elemnt ID

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, stripe.js

Is it possible to retrieve the card element object by referencing the ID of the DOM element that it is attached to, with the Stripe elements API in Javascript? For example, if I create the card element like this:

```
var card = elements.create('card', {style: style});
card.mount('#card-element');
...
...
var card = elements.retrieve(card-element') // in some other function
```

...or do I have to store the card object in a variable? The reason I'm asking is because I would like to clear the credit card details entered in the form at a later stage, and I was hoping there was a way to retrieve the card object without actually storing a reference to it in memory.

Comment: in second parameter of create you have not added attribute id

Comment: @AbhishekShukla I don't understand. The docs don't mention setting ID attribute in that function: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#elements-create - And anyway, how does that help me retrieve the object after creating it?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the card element? `#card-element` is just a placeholder `<div>` or similar in your layout. The actual Elements form is hosted in an iframe created by Stripe and you don't have access to the internals.

Comment: @duck I just want to get hold of the card object so I can clear the form. Like I was saying, I know I can store a reference to it in memory, but I was just hoping there's a way to retrieve it dynamically e.g. `var card = elements.retrieve('card-element')` without storing the reference

Comment: What you should be able to do is `card.clear()` --- see https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#other-methods

Comment: @duck I know that, but I need a reference to the card object first!

Comment: There's no way to retrieve the card element, you'd use `card` above.

Example that clears the field, hit the 'clear' button https://jsfiddle.net/3pyr9r3e/1/